# Are messages sent to groups delivered to every user at the same time?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I was wondering if every user of a group will receive messages at the same time (disregarding the network latency) or if Telegram delivers messages in chunks, which mean some members would see the message earlier than others. Are messages delivered to the Web client and the phone clients at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Telegram transfer message at low latency, so all account/device should receive messages at same time.

You can prove this yourself by using two account in different network and receive messages.